# Extract Token from Curl Request

Tags: python, authentication, curl, token

I have the following request:

```
curl --user world:hello http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/auth/
```

which returns following outpu:

> {"status":"SUCCESS","token":"Mjg2NDA3NDUzMzY0MDgyMDc3NzM5NDg3MjcwODA4ODU5MTIyMjE0"}

How can I store token in a variable for later use? as below

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
'Token': 'TOKENadasfsdfsdfsdfsdsfgsfgfgfadfdgdf'
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's `json` and `subprocess` libraries will help - just invoke the `curl` command from a Python subprocess, parse the resulting JSON, and save the result to a variable.

Comment: Making a sub-process with `curl` is overkill when you're going use Python anyway. `requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/auth/', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('world', 'hello'))` would be more straightforward.

Comment: @Tomalak I certainly wouldn't call it an *overkill*, but if you're willing to introduce third-party dependencies, then yes `requests` is certainly your best bet.  Granted that `curl` is not platform-agnostic, and `requests` is.

Comment: so @alex how would you do it ?

Comment: You can do it with the built-in urllib2, just a whole lot less conveniently. Platform-independence ist not even my main concern, but things like *"not starting a separate process (expensive) to do something as cheap as a single HTTP request"* and *"properly handling the character encoding"*, which would be guaranteed with `requests`, but I am not so sure with subprocess.

Comment: And if I had to make a guess here, the OP is using curl mainly because the API documentation has curl examples, not because there would be a real reason to use it.

Comment: My initial reading of the question was more like "how do I invoke bash commands from Python" rather than "how do I make HTTP requests from Python".  `requests` is absolutely the best option for the latter.  I kind of read it more as the former - your advice is probably better on the whole.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using cURL and asking for python solution I suggest passing that curl output to python and execute this code which decode input's json and print's the token:

```
curl --user world:hello http://127.0.0.1:9000/api/auth/ | python -c "import sys,json;print(json.load(sys.stdin)['token'])"
```

Comment: well what I want is to get the token and then use it python keyword for Automation testing, what do you recommend ?